# preact-router/match without babel

Tags: javascript, preact, preact-router

Preact brags that it [doesn't need build tools](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#no-build-tools-route), but I don't see a way to make `preact-router/match` work. When I do:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { Match } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact-router@3.2.1/src/match.js';
</script>
```

it complains about the `<Match>` tags in [the file](https://unpkg.com/preact-router@3.2.1/src/match.js):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

And [this one](https://unpkg.com/preact-router@3.2.1/match.js) is apparently not a JavaScript module. Is there a way to make it work? Alternatively, what are the changes to be done to `preact-router` to make it work?

Comment: Well, firstly, `preact` != `preact-router`. They're different packages and, generally, client side routing is rarely done without build tools. It doesn't often make sense to do that. What do you mean "it complains"? You need to provide an actual error/warning.

Comment: Well, I understand that `preact` != `preact-router`. But `preact` makes it sound like it can be used without `babel`, but `preact` without a router... is not always useful. And I understand that in production bundlers are usually employed, but I needed it for a test page. Like, you know, when you want to give people something small, that they can copy, paste and run. Ended up using `react`. And added the error message.

Comment: `preact` can be used without babel. It has no requirement on it. That not being useful to your needs doesn't mean that it isn't of benefit to someone else. There's a multitude of ways to build apps without even needing a router, like with SSR. If you just need a test page I fail to see why a router is needed. You can copy, paste, run a `preact` based UI just fine. `preact-router` is for making a full-fledged SPA which has very few reasons to not have build tooling.

Answer (score 1):

The `preact` and `preact-router` are two different packages. `preact-router` itself has a dependency on `preact`. So, there is a dependency graph. To resolve this dependency graph without any builder within the browser itself, you need System.js or equivalent.

Alternately, instead of loading `preact-router` as a `Module`, import it as a normal self-bundled IIFE script as:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/preact-router@3.2.1/dist/preact-router.js"></script>
```

Just ensure that before this script is loaded `preact` is also available globally. So, you should have:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/preact@10.5.13/dist/preact.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/preact-router@3.2.1/dist/preact-router.js"></script>
```

#### Further explanation.

To use ES bundle, you should use from this location:

`https://unpkg.com/browse/preact-router@3.2.1/dist/preact-router.es.js`

If you open this file you will notice that it imports from the `preact` library as:

`import { Component, cloneElement, createElement, toChildArray } from 'preact';`

When you load this as `module` type in browser and when browser encounters this import statement, it cannot figure from where it has to exactly get the `preact` dependency. Is it relative to the CDN? Is it relative to the domain from where you are loading the app? Or, is it relative to the path shown in address bar of the browser?

In case of TypeScript/Bable or front-end blunder like Webpack, it generally pulls it from node_modules using Node resolution algorithm. But browser doesn't have knowledge of node_modules. You have to teach it. At compile time, we use module bundler whereas at runtime, if you need to resolve modules, you need module loader like **System.js**.

There are four types of imports in ES Modules

```
// 1. Bare imports (Not supported by browsers directly)
import { Component } from 'preact';

// 2. Relative imports (Supported)
import { X } from './x.js';

// 3. Root relative imports (Supported)
import { X } from '/relative/to/site/root/x.js';

// 4. Absolute imports (Supported)
import { render } from 'https://unpkg.com/preact@10.5.13/dist/preact.module.js';
```

Thus, even if your library is shipped as ES module, internally it has dependency on **bare** import specified `'preact'` which browser cannot resolve.

Comment: Okay, I did what you told. Well, actually I did that before asking the question. Now, where's [`Match`](https://unpkg.com/preact-router@3.2.1/dist/preact-router.js)? Also, can you possibly provide an example of using `SystemJS`? And can you explain why `preact` works from an es module? What they did to make it work, and what `preact-router` didn't?